# Why don't child elements show inside an ng-if div when it's true?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-if div as follows:

```
<div ng-if="colorSelected" ng-cloak>
  <h6>My Color</h6>
</div>
```

When `colorSelected` is true, the inner header element never shows up. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong?"* Probably, since it isn't working. The template looks fine.

Comment: Have you confirmed 100% that colorSelected is true?  More often than not, in a situation like this, colorSelected hasn't got the value you expect.  Try hard-coding the ng-if to 'true' and see what happens.  Also, try outputting colorSelected to the console so you can see what the value actually is.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that `colorSelected` is not true.

Comment: Well, the outer div does show up, I have a lot of other elements associated with just that div, so I know that 'colorSelected' does get set to true, however, nothing inside it shows up.

Comment: Is this your actual use for it? You should know that ng-if creates it's own scope. So if you are trying to display elements that are related to your scope outside of the ng-if, those things will not show up.

Comment: I tested it with just setting 'colorSelected' to true, and the inner header element still doesn't show up. The outer div does

Comment: It's an over simplified version of it, the outer div is a drop down that only shows up if a color is selected, and then I have a tool tip that's associated with the dropdown

Comment: where are you getting the data for the dropdown?

Comment: The dropdown data is from the angular model associated with it. I've left a lot of the extra attributes out just to make it cleaner to see, but I can add them back in if that's useful. I wanted to see if there is something that I am blatantly missing that I wasn't aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-show instead of ng-if.

ng-if creates it's own scope so any scope variables you use inside of an ng-if will be related to a different scope. For example...

```
<div ng-if='selectedColors'>
  {{iAmDefinedInAController}}
</div>
```

The variable 'iAmDefinedInAController' will be empty even if it is defined in the controller because a new scope is created inside the ng-if.

ng-show does not do this, so just use that and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

it should word.

Probably your modal 'colorSelected' is not binded.

use "ng-if = true" and see if it works