# How to repeat elements pulled from an array inside a javascript object literal with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm repeating elements from a big javascript object literal. Currently, I display the tabbed navigation, image, and title for each product correctly. I cannot get the info to display correctly however. I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in tab.sections" class="product">            
    <div  ng-repeat="child in section.children" ng-if="productIsActive(child, $index)">
        <div class="additionalProductInfo">                             
            <nav class="secondaryTabbedNavigation">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active" ng-repeat="pTabs in child.productTabs">
                        <a class="activelink" href="#">{{pTabs.title}}</a>  //title of each tab                 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="productImage">
            <img ng-src="{{ child.productImageURL }}"/> //the product image
        </div>
        <div class="productInfo">
             <h2 class="productTitle">{{ child.title}}</h2> //the product title
             <div ng-repeat="info in pTabs.infoData" class="productDescription">
                 <p>
                    {{info[1]}} //product info goes here. 
                 </p>                                                   
             </div>                           
        </div>              
    </div>    
</div>
```

I also tried "`{{info}}`" , "`{{info[i][i]}}`", and a couple things using `$index`. But when "`{{info}}`" didn't display anything, I figured I was retrieving the data incorrectly.

Here is the "tabs" javascript object that all this info comes from:

[image: image of tabs javascript object]

As you can see the product info is in a two dimensional array (the first array with the labels of what the information is (e.g. "Title", "Link") and the corresponding information is in the second array. I know this may not be ideal, but this information is currently grabbed from .csv files that prone to changing
and I cannot change how they come into this javascript object.

I know this may seem overcomplicated but this is about as deep as I need to go to get data from the large javascript object and I'm very close.

How can I get the contents from the second array in the two dimensional array (`infoData[1]`) to display like I did with the tabs, image, and title.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: InfoData is an array so you need to loop it and get each element to display

Comment: @MaxZoom Hey Max, thanks for the input. It's my first time using angular, do you mean use ng-repeat to "loop" through it in HTML, or do I need a javascript method that loops through the infodata array for the appropriate product using $index? Thanks.

Comment: Is it just the {{info}} stuff that isnt showing?

Comment: Yes, ng-repeat will do

Comment: You also have an ng-if on each repeated item for itself. So you most likely are having scope issues. ng-if creates its own new scope when those elements are created. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437153/why-dont-child-elements-show-inside-an-ng-if-div-when-its-true/28437424#28437424